# v2/venues/suggestcompletion doesn't support multibyte characters?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to send following request:

> v2/venues/suggestCompletion?ll=35.6886,139.6989&query=%E6%96%B0%E5%AE%BF%E9%A7%85&oauth_token={TOKEN}&v=20120118

I've received following reply:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 200
    }
    notifications: [
        {
            type: "notificationTray"
            item: {
                unreadCount: 0
            }
        }
    ]
    response: {
        minivenues: [ ]
    }
}
```

I tried different query​​, the results were the same. (0 count)

Suggest Completion doesn't support multi-byte characters?

Answer (score 1):

We plan to support multibyte characters in the near future. Thanks for bringing it to our attention